# install couchnode(couchbase nodejs client) with compiling error on osx

Tags: c++, gcc, couchbase, node-gyp, couchnode

afer installed libcouchbase, I excuted

```
sudo npm install couchbase
```

It reported error:

```
npm WARN cannot run in wd couchbase@1.2.4 (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0) (wd=/Users/mymac/node_modules/couchbase)
```

then I went to node_modules/couchbase and executed

```
npm install
```

It outputted the log error:

```
../deps/lcb/src/compat.c:194:36: warning: missing field 'v' initializer [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
    struct lcb_create_st cst = { 0 };
                                   ^
1 warning generated.
../src/logger.h: In instantiation of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]':
../src/logger.h:74:   instantiated from here
../src/logger.h:74: error: explicit instantiation of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]' but no definition available
../src/logger.h: In instantiation of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]':
../src/logger.h:74:   instantiated from here
../src/logger.h:74: error: explicit instantiation of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]' but no definition available
../src/logger.h: In instantiation of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]':
../src/logger.h:74:   instantiated from here
../src/logger.h:74: error: explicit instantiation of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]' but no definition available
../src/logger.h: In instantiation of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]':
../src/logger.h:74:   instantiated from here
../src/logger.h:74: error: explicit instantiation of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]' but no definition available
make: *** [Release/obj.target/couchbase_impl/src/couchbase_impl.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:807:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/couchbase
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.28
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

It lookes like node-gyp can not compile the source code correctly

if I use the code

```
 var couchbase = require('couchbase');
 var db = new couchbase.Connection({
     bucket: "default"

 },
 function(err) {
     if (err) throw err;
     db.set('testdoc1', {
         name: 'Frank1'
     }, function(err, result) {
         if (err) throw err;
         db.get('testdoc1', function(err, result) {
             if (err) throw err;
             console.log(result.value);
             // {name: Frank}
         });
     });
 });
```

console reports

```
Users/mymac/node_modules/couchbase/lib/binding.js:17
      throw e;
            ^
Error: dlopen(/Users/mymac/node_modules/couchbase/prebuilt/win/x64/couchbase_impl.node, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/mymac/node_modules/couchbase/prebuilt/win/x64/couchbase_impl.node: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x4D 0x5A 0x90 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x00 0x00
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at bindings (/Users/mymac/node_modules/couchbase/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:74:15)
    at tryLoadBinding (/Users/mymac/node_modules/couchbase/lib/binding.js:13:31)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mymac/node_modules/couchbase/lib/binding.js:31:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

it can not find out the correct couchbase_impl.node(there is nothing)

[image]

so it goes to prebuilt and get the wrong platform version

```
/Users/mymac/node_modules/couchbase/prebuilt/win/x64/couchbase_impl.node
```

I try to install couchnode on centos, ubuntu, even 1 year before on osx same mac without any problem.

I am not sure if I have changed something/configuration such as gcc to clang when did other job, does it affect this?

I tried

```
export CC=gcc
export CXX=gcc
export CXXFLAGS=-mmacosx-version-min=10.8
```

or

```
export CC=clang
export CXX=clang
export CXXFLAGS=-mmacosx-version-min=10.8
```

and reinstall couchnode
but none worked

Your comment welcome

Comment: You don't indicate your path for your variables there.  Not couchnode's fault, but you may try using homebrew's gcc.  I ran into some issues with MacOS's latest build tools that went away with homebrew's gcc.  This was after an upgrade to mavericks where everything worked with the previous xcode gcc.

Comment: Thanks I will try, is it possible reply as answer, if it works for me I will accept it

Comment: @arachide Hi. I have the same problem since thursday using a Mac OSX. The same project on windows and other OSX machines works fine. Did you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

had related error: "Error: dlopen([...]/app/node_modules/couchbase/prebuilt/win/x64/couchbase_impl.node, 1): no suitable image found"

I was able to resolve this is on OS X 10.9.5 with xcode 6.0.1

Install a fresh copy of libcouchbase:

```
$ brew install libcouchbase
```

This will install libcouchbase into `/usr/local/Cellar/libcouchbase/2.4.1` (or whatever version is current).
Next install Node-SDK via npm

```
$ npm install --couchbase-root=/usr/local/Cellar/libcouchbase/2.4.1 couchbase
```

looks like you need to declare --couchbase-root= when installing on OS X